# Node Js Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redis, try-catch

Hello StackOverFlow Army,
im getting

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Error in this code.

```
getUserInfo: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { id } = req.user;
      
      // Check is User Data present in Redis
      redis_client.GET("USER_" + id, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
          return res.status(500).json({ msg: "Server Error!" });
        }

        // If present Return User data
        // Return User data
        user = JSON.parse(user);
        if (user) return res.json({ user });
      });

      // Else Fetch Data from Database
      const user = await Users.findById(id).select("-password");

      // Set to Redis
      redis_client.SET(
        "USER_" + id.toString(),
        JSON.stringify(user),
        "EX",
        10,
        (err, reply) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            return res.status(500).json({ msg: "Server Error!" });
          }
        }
      );

      // Return User data
      res.json({ user });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: error.message }); // Line 77
    }
  },
```

Error On Line 77.

Please Help me, i cannot see why it is happening. Im sending response and there is no collision between sending response. Is it a good practice to store a user data in redis for faster fetching.
The Expiry time is very low like 10s so if user spam refresh it will help to fetch faster. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Convert all callback functions to new functions that return Promise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your else part inside the callback function of redis_client.GET , just below this line

****if (user) return res.json({ user });**

what happens now is, if this above if condition goes true , then also the the code will move to the next line as return statement will just return from the callback function and not end the response cycle.